# after using removeChars() in textbox in fabric.js the __lineWidths and position of the cursor is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to build a sort of designer with fabric.js What I'm trying to achieve is to restrict the number of characters of user input. I'm doing this by checking the width of the canvas and textbox property __lineWidths. So then the __lineWidths exceeds the width of the canvas, the last character is deleted by removeChars().

The problem is that is works only once, till the moment when the condition is met for the first time, then it stops working because after the removeChars() execute the __lineWidths seems not to be updated. It is increasing by each further input.

Furthermore this is probably causing also a wrong cursor position. the cursor stays in the position of the removed character.

I have made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vynoj7ar/37/) to demonstrate the issue. I have also put this piece of code below.

Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong? then how it can be done the propper way?

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
   width: 300,
   height: 50
 });

var text = new fabric.Textbox(
 '123456789', {
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 40,
  fill: '#000',
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  fontFamily: 'ANWB'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.item(0).enterEditing();
canvas.item(0).hiddenTextarea.focus();


canvas.item(0).hiddenTextarea.onkeydown = function(event) {
//forbid use of ENTER
if (event.key == 'Enter' || event.which == 10 || event.which == 13) {

event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
console.log('passed enter forbid');
}
}

/*text.hiddenTextarea.onblur = function(event){
    if (canvas.item(id).isEditing === true){
        setTimeout(function () { 
            canvas.item(id).hiddenTextarea.focus(); 
        }, 20);

    }
}*/


text.on('changed', function(options) {
$('#line-width').append('<p> line-width = ' + this.__lineWidths[0] + '</p>');

if (this.__lineWidths[0] >= (canvas.width - 40)) {
$('#line-width').append('<p><b>Characters length in __lineWidths[0] is longer than the specified number</b></p>');

this.removeChars((this._text.length - 1), (this._text.length0));
text.hiddenArea.focus();
$('#line-width').append('<p>line-width after the removeChar() = ' + this.__lineWidths[0] + '</p>');

}
});
```